# How to solve laravel Relationship

Tags: laravel

I am very confused with this relationship, i tried video tutorial but couldn't get how to solve this relationship. Thanks in Advance If someone can explain me.

I tried in mysql that's working fine but i am learning laravel and want to do like this.

```
User
---------
id
email
name
address1
address2
country

Product
-------
id
internal_name
display_name

Licence
------
id
product_id
key

Linked_licence
--------
licence_id
user_id
```

User has many licences through linked_licence

I am using like this but getting error :

```
public function licences()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Licence::class, UserLicence::class, 'licences.id', 'user_id', 'licence_id');
    }
```

User has many products through licence

```
public function licences()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, Licences::class, 'licences.id', 'user_id', 'licence_id');
        }
```

Product belongs to licence

```
public function licences()
        {
            return $this->belogsTo(Product::class);
        }
```

This is error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'licences_user.licences.id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `licences`.*, `licences_user`.`licences`.`id` from `licences` inner join `licences_user` on `licenscs_user`.`id` = `licences`.`user_id` where `licences_user`.`licences`.`id` is null)
```

But problem is i don't know about laravel relationship how to create these kind of queries.

Updated :

```
SELECT
  `users`.*,
  `licences`.*,
  `licenses_user`.`license_id`
FROM `licences`
  INNER JOIN `licenses_user` ON `licenses_user`.`license_id` = `licences`.`id`
  INNER JOIN users ON licenses_user.user_id = users.id
WHERE `licenses_user`.`license_id` = 1
```

Above query working but how to use with laravel ?

Comment: 1. you have a typo in your last code, 2. what error are you getting?

Comment: Updated any post

Comment: try changing licences.id to id only.

Comment: actually i tried but same error, problem in relationship query

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel version 5.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142342/discussion-between-earon-and-taha-paksu).

Comment: I think you must use `hasMany` Instead `hasManyThrough‍`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be to do with this line of code

```
Licences::class, 'licences.id', 'user_id', 'licence_id');
```

it appears that the column does not exist in the table from looking at your error.

double check your spelling, it looks like it's looking inside the table called  `licences_user` for a column named `lincences.id`